# A reference for equivalent ways of solving the continuity equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Consider a vector field
$$
X:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R^d
$$
we can define the continuity equation in a distributional sense for a curve of measures $\mu:[0,T]\to\mathcal M_b(\mathbb R^d)$ as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mu_t+\mathrm{div}(X\mu_t)=0.
$$

The only way known to me on how to solve this equation is via characteristics, i.e. finding the flow of solutions
$$
\dot{\gamma}_t=X(\gamma_t)
$$
and calling it $\Phi$ and then pushing forward whatever positive initial data $\mu_0$ we have defining a solution
$$
\mu_t=(\Phi_t)_\#\mu_0.
$$

My question is: what other ways of solving the continuity equation are there? I think I heard of a way to treat it as an optimization problem of sorts and therefore as the infimum or supremum of a functional.
Can you give me a reference for equivalent ways to solve the continuity equation?
In any setting is fine, be it Euclidean space or whatever there can be.